# Express JS - post method - req.body is getting undefined even I use app.use(express.json())

Tags: node.js, express, post, undefined

my code is like this -

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const { open } = require("sqlite");
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");

const dbPath = path.join(__dirname, "moviesData.db");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))

let database = null;

const initializeDBAndServer = async () => {
  try {
    database = await open({
      filename: dbPath,
      driver: sqlite3.Database,
    })
    app.listen(5353, () => {
      console.log(`server is running at http://localhost:5353/`)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
    process.exit(1)
  }
}

initializeDBAndServer();

app.post("/myId", async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  console.log(`requested Id is ${id}`);
  res.send(`requested Id id ${id}`);
})
```

my request is -

```
POST http://localhost:5353/myId/
Content-Type: "application/json"

{
  "id": 123456 
}
```

And the console and response is coming the same

```
requested Id is undefined
```

I have used - **app.use(express.json())**. It is not working.
And also installed body-parser and also tried. It also not worked.

So, please help me out by giving the correct code.

Comment: are you sending post data with proper `Content-Type`? and can you post the curl command for the post call that you make to the server

Comment: Content-Type: "application/json"

I am using this

Comment: can you post the curl call equivalent, because your code seem to be working fine for me. I could the see `id` getting logged correctly.

Comment: how are you sending request can you add that code to your question

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: added the request

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show **exactly** how you're making the request. If it's from the command line show what commands you're executing. If it's code, include the code. If you're using a tool like Postman, please include a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` in your request is incorrect, it should be `application/json`, not `"application/json"`:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```